# User inserting Alphabet into array and controlling if there are repetitions and order of input Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create an array of 26  and insert in it the alphabet letters, then I have to control if there are any repetitions and the order of input eg: `a,b,c` or `z,y,x`.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Esercizio4 {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int ripetions;

    public Esercizio4(){  
        char alfa[] = new char[26];
        for (int i=0;i<=26;i++){
            System.out.println("Insert a letter");
            alfa[i]=sc.next().charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I googled how to make a control of the input being correct (accepting only letters) but I couldn't find much or it was hard to understand.
The second part might be easier but still how to control if there are repetitions and if the order is increasing/decreasing (`a,b,c`/`z,x,y`).

Comment: I voted to close as too broad (two "and"s in the title is a smell) - you're asking three things here. 1. how to input (which is too basic a question for SO) 2. how to check for repetitions 3. how to check for order (and you're vague about this -- what if the input is not sorted at all e.g. "acb"?).

Comment: 26 strictly increasing letters cannot have repetitions.

Comment: The first question was about the input exclusively being a letter (no numbers or other carachters)

Comment: Look at `Character.isLetter()`

Comment: Asking for too many things here and the question is unclear. To ensure clean input from user, just use input validation. Question itself if contradicting. How can an array of 26 with strictly letters having repetitions?

Answer (score 1):

To know if the char is a letter you have to compare the numerical representation of the char.

[Have a look at this table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

i.e.:

The letter `a = 97` while `A = 65`.

What that tells us is that a char can range between a value of `97 - 122` for lowercase letters and `65 - 90` for capital letters.

Then it is only a question of looping trough your array and comparing the values to figure out if you have repetitions or invalid characters!

PS: You can also use values to re-order your array. Check out sorting algorythms.

[Java sorting algorythms](http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/)